# Dockerfile returns dns error when trying to create an image

Tags: python, docker, build, dns, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a docker image, return error:

> DNS lookup error

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

LABEL maintainer="r.ofc@hotmail.com"

ENV PROJECT_ROOT /app
WORKDIR $PROJECT_ROOT

RUN apk update \
    && apk add mariadb-dev \
        gcc\
        python3-dev \
        pango-dev \
        cairo-dev \
        libtool \
        linux-headers \
        musl-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        openssl-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        zlib-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

i'm runing kubernetes locale useing minikube

Comment: [Please do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Are you behind a corporate or local proxy/firewall?

Comment: ok sorry, i'm testing local

Comment: Please add the FULL error. Testing local means nothing: you have a proxy? Do you have a firewall blocking some kind of call? The same URL working on your host machine?